# Fitting regression model in R using rasters and numeric vectors - not as usual as it seems

Tags: r, vector, raster, logistic-regression

I'm trying to fit the Firth's Penalized Maximum Likelihood Estimation for logistic regression implemented in [logistf package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logistf/logistf.pdf) to a set of rasters but I'm in trouble to implement it using rasters and numeric vectors. Let's illustrate the problem:

```
library(raster)
library(logistf)

# Creating 2 rasters to reproduce what I'm facing
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)

# binary response raster-variable with 9 bands/layers
s1 <- lapply(1:9, function(i) setValues(r, sample(0:1,ncell(r),replace = T)))
s1 <- stack(s1)

# one explanatory raster-variable
val <- sample(0:60,ncell(r),replace = T)
s2 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10,vals=val)

plot(s1)
plot(s2)

# a second explanatory variable as a numeric vector: Nine values just as s1 has 9 bands/layers (not a coincidence)
exp_2 <- c(27.00,30.02,31.07,32.72,33.73,35.12,35.65,36.06,38.32)
```

Now, I want to fit the model using logistf (i have statistical reasons for this, not reproduced here) using calc from raster package. That's where the mystery lives.

The rationale in the problem formulation is that each raster cell would follow the glm formula:

```
s1 ~ 27.00 + corresponding cell in s2 + 27.00:corresponding cell in s2
s1 ~ 30.02 + corresponding cell in s2 + 30.02:corresponding cell in s2
s1 ~ 31.07 + corresponding cell in s2 + 31.07:corresponding cell in s2
```

... and so on for all 9 values in `exp_2`.

I tried something like this:

```
fun <- function(x) { logistf(x ~ exp_2 + s2 + exp_2:s2)$coefficients }
coefs <- calc(s1,fun)
```

But it was clear it wouldn't work. Probably because different dimensions/number of layers in this dataset. I'm getting the error message

```
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
cannot use this function
```

Any idea would be appreciated. Ideas?

Comment: I have my doubts you can use `calc` to implement this function. Another possibility would be `overlay`, but I also doubt that would work. Regardless, your `fun` returns 4 coefficients for one cell, which I'm not sure is what you want. As an alternative approach, you could convert the rasters to matrices for your calculations and then put the result into a raster again.

Comment: Thanks @Val. You are right. I'm trying everything I can and nothing is working. I have managed to do this some time ago converting rasters to data frames, but I'm wondering if it wasn't an unnecessary manipulation... It takes time and several steps. So I'm now looking for a more straightforward approach. But not sure if I'll achieve it. I'll keep trying a bit more.